# A relation concerning the "sum of squares" counting function $r_2(n)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sequences-and-series

This is a [re-post from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2963036/72031) as I did not get any response there.

Let $r_2(n)$ denote the number of ways in which a positive integer $n$ can be expressed as the sum of squares of two integers. Here the sign as well as order of summands matters. Also by convention we set $r_2(0)=1$.

G. H. Hardy mentions the following formula in his book *Ramanujan : Twelve Lectures on Subjects Suggested by His Life and Work* (see page $82$) $$\sum_{0\leq n<x} \frac{r_2(n)}{\sqrt{x-n}}=2\pi\sqrt {x} +\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{r_2(n)}{\sqrt{n}}\sin 2\pi\sqrt{nx} \tag{1}$$ This is preceded by mention of another formula of Ramanujan $$\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{r_{2}(n)}{\sqrt{n + a}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + a)b}} = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}\frac{r_{2}(n)}{\sqrt{n + b}}e^{-2\pi\sqrt{(n + b)a}}\tag{2}$$ which is [proved here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1357253/72031). Next Hardy says that the above formula of Ramanujan is valid when $\sqrt{a}, \sqrt{b} $ have positive real parts. Putting $a=xe^{it} $ for $x>0, x\notin\mathbb{Z} ,0<t<\pi$ in $(2)$ and letting $t\to\pi$ followed by equating imaginary parts and setting $b=0$ the relation $(1)$ is obtained.

And then comes the remark "this deduction, of course, is not a *proof* of $(1)$ and I do not know that there is any proof standing in the literature".

> Has a proof of $(1)$ been found since? If so a reference would be greatly appreciated. Can the deduction mentioned above be fixed by making some modification? Any other approaches to prove $(1)$ are also welcome.

Comment: There is a relatively recent paper "The Circle Problem of Gauss and the Divisor Problem of Dirichlet–Still Unsolved" of Berndt, Kim, and Zaharescu (see https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~berndt/articles/circledivisorsurvey.pdf) which doesn't quite answer the question but which is relevant. They indicate at the top of page 5 that an analogous formula was proven with the square root replaced by any higher power by Chandrasekharan and Narasimhan. Since they don't mention the square root power, my guess is that it's not in the literature. (cont.)

Comment: I think it should be possible to prove as long as the sum on the right hand side converges, but, without giving it too much thought, it's not obvious that this sum does converge in the traditional sense. Bruce Berndt would be a good person to contact for better information. (Another comment: you may be interested in 'smooth' versions of this formula, if you haven't seen them. See for example identity (1.7) of the survey https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0304187.)

Comment: @BradRodgers: Thanks! I will have a look at papers you linked in the comments.

Comment: By the way, I guess the arxiv link doesn't work as is -- you'll have the delete the period at the end that gets included with it...